# Javascript: order of "for" cycle through object props

Tags: javascript

If I have an object an cycle through its properties:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

for (var prop in obj){
   console.log(obj[prop])
}
```

Will I inevitably always get: 1, 2, 3 as a result? On what it may depend? Is other result practically real?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no guarantee in the language regarding the order of iteration in object properties.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) :

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an
>   arbitrary order (see the delete operator for more on why one cannot
>   depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a
>   cross-browser setting)

and

> Although ECMAScript makes iteration order of objects
>   implementation-dependent, it may appear that all major browsers
>   support an iteration order based on the earliest added property coming
>   first (at least for properties not on the prototype). However, in the
>   case of Internet Explorer, when one uses delete on a property, some
>   confusing behavior results, preventing other browsers from using
>   simple objects like object literals as ordered associative arrays. In
>   Explorer, while the property value is indeed set to undefined, if one
>   later adds back a property with the same name, the property will be
>   iterated in its old position--not at the end of the iteration sequence
>   as one might expect after having deleted the property and then added
>   it back.
>
> So if you want to simulate an ordered associative array in a
>   cross-browser environment, you are forced to either use two separate
>   arrays (one for the keys and the other for the values), or build an
>   array of single-property objects, etc.

If you want a guarantee, you have to use an array. You may construct it by sorting the property key if you like.

Comment: I've never encountered the wrong order while such looping, and did tests to do that, but it is always 1,2, 3 =)

Comment: It's basically implementation dependent. And as no serious developer ever relied on the most common behavior, a different implementation might very well appear.